# Coercive bilinear form from Poisson equation with Robin boundary conditions

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, bilinear-form

I need to find if the bilinear form arising from the following problem is coercive or not : $$-v\Delta u = f \quad \text{in } \Omega$$ 
$$v\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} +hu = 0 \quad \text{on } \partial\Omega$$

where $v >0$ and $h>0$ are constants, which is Poisson's equation with a Robin boundary condition. This is for a mathematics FEM class.

What I've done so far is find the variational form of the problem :
$$v\int_{\Omega} \nabla u\cdot \nabla w + h\int_{\partial \Omega}u w= \int_{\Omega} fw $$ 
for all $w \in H^1(\Omega)$. So my bilinear form is 
$$a(w,w)=v\int_{\Omega} \nabla w\cdot \nabla w + h\int_{\partial \Omega}w^2$$
and I want to show that $\exists \alpha >0$ such that $$a(w,w)\ge\alpha \|w\|^2_{H^1(\Omega)}$$
I've searched a lot on this site and others and the answer seems to be it is indeed coercive : [here (Last Question)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361423/variational-formulation-of-robin-boundary-value-problem-for-poisson-equation-in/361592#361592), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166399/how-to-find-if-a-bilinear-form-is-coercive) and [here](https://mathproblems123.wordpress.com/2012/10/22/weak-formulation-for-laplace-equation-with-robin-boundary-conditions/).

However, these answers use concepts that we have not covered in class (sequences of functions in $H^1$, compactness argument, Friedrich inequality  namely). So I was wondering if the coercivity could be proven in a simpler way.

What's more, I asked my teacher and he told me that with what we've covered in class we are not able to show it is coercive, so that I should instead look for a counter-example, which seems contradictory to me because I can't find a counter-example if the bilinear form really is coercive...

Comment: Looks coercive to me, assuming $n$ is the exterior normal.

Comment: Yes, $n$ is the exterior normal vector.